# How to change day color in default date picker

Tags: android, datepicker

Currently the date picker is [look like this](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipNENU10ozdNSvCs7kwFI2X4r5IzpRpDkVdDlfBQcNFH5FmVvTvjVItpAQK1cS90Sg/photo/AF1QipMfdIAR1wMT21z1AlZgYnVjPefT14KeOF-c7xHc?key=V09PMTU1MC1Ic0ZkOVRDaVpaRVFDLUVyMmtZS2pR).

I want to change the color date color ( currently set to black.)

Datepicker theme.

```
<style name="myDatePickertheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
            <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/white</item>
            <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text</item>
        </style>
```

Solution Tried:

```
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
```

in the custom theme.

Min api=17

App theme

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:background">@color/primary_background</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_background</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/primary_background</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/primary_background</item>
        <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/myDialog</item>
        <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/myDatePickertheme</item>

    </style>
```

ANy hint?

Comment: Have you tried the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29014475/6155248) ? Hope it help you!

Comment: Yes I have tried..  but no helps. @TahmidRahman

Comment: Date picker always choose colorPrimary and colorAccent in your app theme. Pls check that is the same color u have got i the calendar ?

Comment: Try this then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738089/change-datepicker-dialog-color-for-android-5-0

Comment: I guess you'r nearer to solution. Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30252559/6005977)

Comment: I think colorPrimary and colorAccent will change the day font color.. @Nithinlal

Comment: @AnkitaShah I had try that but no help..

Comment: I had tried all the option mentioning on that link. but nothing help.. @Nithinlal

Comment: In this solution, Change theme pragmatically. And they also share images. Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38652903/6005977) once

Comment: can you share your app theme

Comment: @Nithinlal app theme added.

Comment: I have try to use the layout 2 but again no help.. @AnkitaShah

Comment: add these line to the app theme  <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

Comment: I think this will change the complete app coloring.. @Nithinlal. I have tried to add this in the datepicker theme.. day color is changed but not date color.

Comment: I think u can use a third party library for that. https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3779 u can use this library

Comment: I am able to understand what is the exact problem? @Nithinlal

Answer (score 0):

would you try to create a custom `datePicker` then? you may try the solution of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29173521/6155248) ?

Comment: thank for this solution,, I think this will be the last solution if nothing happen. I think to change the font color , simple changes will work.